# How compare a string with a format? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a string like that "CP23332200-01"

I split my string and i get last 5 characters: "00-01" like that:

Dim result As String = PartNo

```
                'for content parts
                If PartNo.Contains("CP") Then

                    If PartNo.Length > 5 Then
                        result = PartNo.Substring(PartNo.Length - 5)
                    End If



                End If
```

Result = "00-01"

How i compare this string with format like that : "int" - "int"
Two numbers  and two numbers
I want to assure you that string "00-01" is always that format.
Note* Result in not always "00-01" but format is always two numbers - and two number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for that:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

'Create one regex obj
Dim regex as new Regex("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$")
'...

If PartNo.Contains("CP") Then
    If PartNo.Length > 5 Then
         result = PartNo.Substring(PartNo.Length - 5)
    End If

    'RegEx match against result
    If regex.IsMatch(result) Then 
        LBL_ERR.Text = "asdas"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Explanation:

`^`     = Start of string

`[0-9]` = only digits allowed

`{2}`   = exact two digits allowed

`$`     = end of string

I checked it with some numbers but you should verify the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/uY1oC7/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want regex then this should work too:

```
If PartNo.Contains("CP") Then

   If PartNo.Length > 5 Then
       result = PartNo.Substring(PartNo.Length - 5)
   End If

   If result.Contains('-') Then
       Dim parts As String() = result.Split(New Char() {"-"c})
       If IsNumeric(parts(0)) and IsNumeric(parts(1))
              LBL_ERR.Text = "asdas"
       End if
   Else
     Exit Sub
   End If

End If
```

Or more clearer version:

```
If PartNo.Contains("CP") Then

   If PartNo.Length > 5 Then
       result = PartNo.Substring(PartNo.Length - 5)
   End If
dim result as boolean = CheckForNumeric(result)
   If result = true then 
     LBL_ERR.Text = "asdas"
   Else
     Exit Sub
   End If
End If



Private Function CheckForNumeric(ByVal result as string) As Boolean
If result.Contains('-') Then
           Dim parts As String() = result.Split(New Char() {"-"c})
           If IsNumeric(parts(0)) and IsNumeric(parts(1))
               return true   
           End if
End if
return false
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Pattern Matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te33kb6t.aspx) using the Like operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
                If PartNo.Contains("CP") Then

                    If PartNo.Length > 5 Then
                        result = PartNo.Substring(PartNo.Length - 5)
                    End If

                    If result Like "##-##" Then
                        LBL_ERR.Text = "asdas"
                    Else
                        Exit Sub
                    End If


                End If
```

result of my problem is that: 
"#" replaces one character